# How can I correct touchscreen configuration (inverted x and y) in 19.04?

Tags: touchscreen, 19.04

I have an old windows tablet that I have managed to install Ubuntu on (a WinBook TW700) and it works pretty well.  I originally installed 16.04 and was able to address the inverted axis through use of xinput-calibrator and editing the 99-configuration.conf file and had the screen working great.  Then I made the mistake of upgrading to 19.04.

in 19.04 I am no longer able to configure the screen at all.  touch is recognized (and now rotation works although this is also inverted) but if I touch the lower right corner the pointer appears in the upper left and vice versa.  the 99-configuration.conf seems to have no effect. How and where can I make adjustments to get this configuration correct? It would be great if I could get both the inverted x and y settings and the screen rotation correct.  Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: **Not a solution**, just a suggestion: Try it with the Unity DE which was the default in 16.04.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thank you for the suggestion.  It was a good idea but unfortunately didn't solve the calibration problem. Interestingly though, there is no screen rotation in Unity so it did have some effect.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me since kernel 4.20 which was the first time I had any touchscreen at all.I had to , and still have to run scripts to rotate and until kernel 5.0 I had to run this following script to calibrate the touch pen and screen.
The key line is:

```
xinput map-to-output $i eDP
```

where `$1` is what you get from xinput and it is a number (which I found could change between boots, so I get it from the name with the `deviceid=` line, mine being ELAN0732:00). note I have to touch the screen to activate the pen to get it to show up in xinput. the number changes all the time.

I had an issue last week with the pen cursor being off where the pen was contacting, but this has, er, magically resolved itself, actually just checked and its back so I need to work on that one. I think my script just fixed it again.

This link helped with the rotations. I still don't have those showing in display settings, though I think it once did. Such is consistent with Ubuntu AMD experiences this year.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation

I made a script saved as RotateMapToOutputs.sh

```
# dont forget to touch the screen first with the pen.
touchscreen=""
pen=""

OIFS=$IFS
search=""ELAN0732:00""

# note that the pen didnt show up until I mapped the standard one or clicked the screen.
# so need to do that first
echo $search

list=$(xinput | grep $search | grep pointer)
echo "list $list"

# just a text file to work with the list.
if [ -f tempxinput.txt ]
then    
    echo " removing tempxinput"
    rm tempxinput.txt
fi

device_id=$(echo "$list" | sed -n 's/.*ELAN0732:00.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')

for i in $device_id
do
echo "id is $i"
xinput map-to-output $i eDP

done
```

I then set a keyboard shortcut to do

```
bash "~/MyScripts/ RotateMapToOutputs.sh"
```

as it seems like you might have troubles with rotation, this is my rotate inverted script and I made a shortcut key as above. (note the maptoputput there might be in error as 14 is no longer that one, so I can then run the above maptooutputs after any rotation if it doesn't calibrate.

```
xrandr --output eDP --rotate inverted &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP
```

normal is:

```
xrandr --output eDP --rotate normal &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP
```

left:

```
xrandr --output eDP --rotate left &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP
```

right:

```
xrandr --output eDP --rotate right &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumbles over this thread looking for a way to configure a pointer to a display using a certain rotation, I'll link my script here: https://github.com/SimonLammer/dotfiles/blob/0b98315b06b9393df6235457007b84831f1646f5/data/scripts/xinput-configure-pointer

It improves on pierrely's answer by allowing the tablet to be limited to a display.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Limits a pointer to a display with an orientation.
# This can be used to limit a rotated graphics tablet to one display.

set -e

ZENITY='zenity --width 500 --height 500'

# Select pointer
pointers=`xinput | grep pointer | tail -n +2 | sed -E 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*((\S+ ?)+[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)]+)\s*id=([0-9]+)\s*(.*)/"\3" "\1" "\4"/'`
#echo $pointers
pointer=`echo $pointers | xargs $ZENITY --list --text "Choose a pointer" --column Id --column Name --column Info`
#echo $pointer

# Select display
displays=`xrandr | grep \ con | sed -E 's/(\S+)[^0-9]*(.*)/"\1" "\2"/'`
#echo $displays
display=`echo $displays | xargs $ZENITY --list --text "Choose a display" --column Id --column Info`
#echo $display

# Map pointer to display to get initial coordinate transformation matrix
xinput map-to-output "$pointer" "$display"
mat0=`xinput list-props $pointer | grep "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" | cut -d ':' -f 2`

# Select orientation
o1="0°C"
o2="90°C"
o3="180°C"
o4="270°C"
orientation=`$ZENITY --list --text "Choose an orientation" --column Orientation --column Name "$o1" "Normal" "$o2" "Rotate left" "$o3" "Invert" "$o4" "Rotate right"`
# https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation
if [ "$orientation" = "$o1" ]; then
  mat1="1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1"
elif [ "$orientation" = "$o2" ]; then
  mat1="0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1"
elif [ "$orientation" = "$o3" ]; then
  mat1="-1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1"
else
  mat1="0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1"
fi

# Multiply matrices (mat2 = mat0 * mat1)
# https://www.mymathtables.com/calculator/matrix/3-cross-3-matrix-multiplication.html
perl_expr="@a=split(/,? /,'$mat0');@b=split(/ /,'$mat1');print \"\"\
  .(\$a[0]*\$b[0]+\$a[1]*\$b[3]+\$a[2]*\$b[6]).\" \".(\$a[0]*\$b[1]+\$a[1]*\$b[4]+\$a[2]*\$b[7]).\" \".(\$a[0]*\$b[2]+\$a[1]*\$b[5]+\$a[2]*\$b[8]).\" \"\
  .(\$a[3]*\$b[0]+\$a[4]*\$b[3]+\$a[5]*\$b[6]).\" \".(\$a[3]*\$b[1]+\$a[4]*\$b[4]+\$a[5]*\$b[7]).\" \".(\$a[3]*\$b[2]+\$a[4]*\$b[5]+\$a[5]*\$b[8]).\" \"\
  .(\$a[6]*\$b[0]+\$a[7]*\$b[3]+\$a[8]*\$b[6]).\" \".(\$a[6]*\$b[1]+\$a[7]*\$b[4]+\$a[8]*\$b[7]).\" \".(\$a[6]*\$b[2]+\$a[7]*\$b[5]+\$a[8]*\$b[8]).\" \"\
  .\"\\n\""
#echo $perl_expr
mat2=`perl -E "$perl_expr"`

xinput set-prop "$pointer" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" $mat2
```